Challenge failed for http 01
I am trying to install SSL certificate on an OJS(open journal systems) website whose url is journal.iba-suk.edu.pk:8089. I am doing so from Ubuntu using certbot. While running command sudo certbot --apache, I am getting the above mentioned error and unable to install SSL certificate.
I ran the command
Sudo certbot --apache 

But the the SSL certificate was not installed as challenge failed. The error message says firewall problem but the firewall is off and it also says make sure domain name is correct and the domain is also correct

certbot only works on port 80 or 443 as your app is running in 8089 certbot might be unable to complete the challenge. you need to proxy pass your app running in 8089 to port 80 as i usually do with nginx. I am sure we can proxy pass in apache too. after you do that you can try applying certificate again.

Could you tell me how to have shell access of ojs website. Suppose username is admin and password is 123

I think I am unable to prove domain ownership.

@AhmedSyed in simple terms the ip of the instance you are hosting your app should be set as A record for the domain(journal.iba-suk.edu.pk) in DNS for you to be able to get certbot certificate. if you haven't set that you wont be able to apply the ssl certificate to you domain that you have setup in you apcahe config.
and by the way you can only proxy pass to port 80 if you application is hosted in another port and apply for the certificate using certbot
